# Instagram API fetching images with Specific Hashtag

Tags: ios, api, instagram

Hi I am pretty new to iOS and the Instagram API. I want to retrieve all pictures with a specific hashtag in an iOS app. How can i do that? Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Start reading about [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/). You need to make use of the following *Tag Endpoint* -

[image]

Once again, Instagram API documentation is very rich. Read about Tag Endpoints [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_search).

Furthermore, if you are new to iOS programming, I would strongly suggest you to complete [Build a Photo Browser iPhone App](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-photo-browser-iphone-app) project by [Team Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/). You will be creating a cool iPhone app for browsing Instagram photos.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try building that app this week.

Comment: @jordanbana Please select the answer as right to consider the topic closed for other users which are asking the same question.