# Download images containing a specific tag with likes from Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I would like to download images with a certain *tag* from Instagram with their likes. With this post I hope to get some advice or tips on how to do this. I have no experience with web scraping related stuff or web API usages. One of my questions is: can you create a program like this in python code or can you only do this using a webpage?

So far I have understood the following. To get images with a certain *tag* you have to:

- need a valid `access_token` to even gain access to images by tag, which can be done like [this](http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token). However, when I sign in you need to give a [website](https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/). Does this indicate that you can only use the API's on websites rather than a python program for instance?
- you use a media [Tag Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728914/instagram-api-fetching-images-with-specific-hashtag) to search for tags by name.

I have no idea what the latest step will return exactly, but I expect that it will give me a specific image id that contains the tag. Correct? Now I will also need to get the likes belonging to these images. Just like latest step from before:

- you use a likes [Tag Endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/) to get a list of users that liked the image of which of course you can get the length.

If I can accomplish all of these steps it seems like I can achieve my original goal. I googled if there was something out there already. The only thing I could find was [InstaRaider](https://github.com/akurtovic/InstaRaider), but this did not seem to fit my description because it web scraped only the images from a specific user and not by tag or its likes. Any suggestions or ideas would be very helpful, I have only programmed in python and Java before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only tell you that for URL you can use the localhost as this:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

OR

```
http://localhost
```

I have also tried to do exactly the same before, but I could not, so I used a website to search for tags and images:

http://iconosquare.com/search/[HASHTAG]